# Get users current date

Tags: date, timezone

I need to check what’s the current date where the user is in.
I don’t need the time, just the current date.
How can i do it?
I'm using codeigniter.
Thanks.

---

I've managed to get the date on the client side.
My problem is that i get an error (0) when trying to parse it using strtotime.
I know that means the string is not ok but when i do an echo it displays ok(07/11/2010).
Here's the code:
javascript:

```
function getthedate(){
var mydate=new Date()
var year=mydate.getYear()
if (year
```

HTML:

```
$curdate="";
$newdate = strtotime ( '-0 year' , strtotime ( $curdate ) ) ;
$curdate=date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );
echo form_hidden('curdate','',$curdate);
```

Comment: codeigniter, being server-side, doesn't know what time or date it is where the user is; but (if his browser is decently well configured) his javascript should know -- and could send you the info via an ajax call.  What javascript framework do you use (if any)?

Comment: jQuery makes it easy to make ajax calls so I'd definitely recommend that in this case -- just send JS that ajaxes you the time as soon as the page is loaded so you can compute the timezone (you need the time, not just the date, since at that very instant the time is sent to it could be 11:59:59.99 PM at the user's location... and a fraction of a second later the user's date would be changed! with the full time you have more robustness).

Comment: @JEagle Be aware that the client computer might not have the date and time set correctly!

Answer (score 0):

The web server and, by extension, your application do not have this information.  You have to get that input from the client side somehow.  A couple of ideas come to mind:

- Ask the user what time zone they're in (e.g., with a form), then calculate their date based on that.
- Use some JavaScript that finds the information automatically (e.g., `getTimezoneOffset()`).  Optionally, submit this information to your app via Ajax.

Comment: Can you point me to some examples so i can learn how to do it?

Comment: Here's an example of using jQuery Ajax with CodeIgniter: http://www.mrforbes.com/thoughts/2009/01/28/a-quick-code-igniter-and-jquery-ajax-tutorial/ - basically you want a controller that will accept the user's data (including user id, time zone, date, or whatever other information you want to pass to the server).  Also see the various jQuery Ajax methods here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: thanks for the links. Will try to get it right since i'm still a newbie in jQuery...